# Apache historical connections log

Tags: apache, connection, logging

Doe anyone know if it's possible to identify the number of connections that a server has had over a given period of time?

are there any logs that keep that kind of information?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use "grep" to get all the lines from the access.log that contain a certain date/time (or range) (and other filter criteria) and pipe it to "wc -l" to count the number of lines, which will give you the number of requests.

Answer (score 4):

I not really sure, but did you have a look at `access.log`? Under linux its usually at `/var/log/apach2/access.log`. Where it is located on your system is defined in yur `httpd.conf` or one other parsed apache configuration.